# How to return all integers from a list into a formatted string?

Tags: python

I have a list of integers and I want all integers to be formatted inside a string. I have tried the following approach:

```
def get_numbers():
    numbers = [1, 3, 5]
    for number in numbers:
        return "{}".format(number)
```

This didn't work and returned the following:

```
get_numbers()
'1'
```

Any ideas to another approach?

Comment: hello, use ' '.join(numbers) maybe?

Comment: What exactly should the result look like? `135`, `1,3,5`, something else?

Comment: I want the format to be 1-3-5 :)

Comment: Fred: Put that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you like to convert an integerlist to a string, (you can use the fstring to enforce the format):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> "-".join([f"{i:.2f}" for i in l]) 
'1.00-2.00-3.00-4.00-5.00-6.00-7.00-8.00-9.00'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to store them in a string object and then return it :

```py
def get_numbers():
    numbers = [1, 3, 5]
    ret = ""
    for number in numbers:
        ret += str(number)
    return ret
```

What you expect is to join your numbers into a string like

```py
def get_numbers():
    numbers = [1, 3, 5]
    separator = '-' #or ''
    return separator.join(numbers)
```

Comment: This is just about the worst way to build up a string value in Python.